# Rolling dice with random bits: Is my methodology flawed or am I overthinking things?

Tags: distributions, python

So I am simply playing around with trying to make a "dice roller" using `random.getrandbits()` and the "wasteful" methodology stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804899/how-to-generate-an-un-biased-random-number-within-an-arbitrary-range-using-the-f/20818831#20818831

My code seems to be working fine, however when I roll D6's the Max\Min ratio is in the 1.004... range but with D100's it's in the 1.05... range. Considering my dataset is only about a million rolls, is this ok or is the pRNG nature of `random` affecting the results? Or am I just being an idiot and overthinking it and it's due to D100s simply having a larger range of values than a D6?

Edit: Max/Min ratio is the frequency of the most common result divided by the frequency of the least common result. For a perfectly fair dice this should be 1.

````py
from math import ceil, log2
from random import getrandbits

def wasteful_die(dice_size: int):
    #Generate minumum binary number greater than or equal to dice_size number of random bits
    bits = getrandbits(ceil(log2(dice_size)))

    #If bits is a valid number (i.e. its not greater than dice_size), yeild
    if bits < dice_size:
        yield 1 + bits


def generate_rolls(dice_size: int, number_of_rolls: int) -> list:
    #Store the results
    list_of_numbers = []

    #Command line activity indicator
    print('Rolling '+f'{number_of_rolls:,}'+' D'+str(dice_size)+'s',end='',flush=True)
    activityIndicator = 0

    #As this is a wasteful algorithm, keep rolling until you have the desired number of valid rolls.
    while len(list_of_numbers) < number_of_rolls:
        #Print a period every 1000 attempts
        if activityIndicator % 1000 == 0:
            print('.',end='',flush=True)

        #Build up the list of rolls with valid rolls.
        for value in wasteful_die(dice_size):
            list_of_numbers.append(value)
        activityIndicator+=1
    print(' ',flush=True)

    #Use list slice just in case something wrong.
    return list_of_numbers[0:number_of_rolls]

#Rolls one million, fourty eight thousand, five hundred and seventy six D6s
print(generate_rolls(6, 1048576), file=open("RollsD6.txt", "w"))

#Rolls one million, fourty eight thousand, five hundred and seventy six D100
print(generate_rolls(100, 1048576), file=open("RollsD100.txt", "w"))
```
````

Comment: Could you tell us what you mean by "max/min" ratio?  BTW, better solutions to this problem (compared to this apparent rejection sampling method) have appeared both here on CV and on the Math site, if you are interested.

Comment: Max min ratio is the frequency of the most common result divided by the frequency of the least common result. For a perfectly fair dice this should be 1. Any links to better solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you.  That's not a useful statistic (and is somewhat surprising to see in this situation) because (a) its interpretation depends on the number of sides on the die and on the simulation size and (b) it is extremely variable.  Consider using the chi-squared statistic instead.

Comment: Thank you. I shall do that